# Modify attribute if node exist with Xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, nodes, simplexml

I'm trying to modify a node attribute if the node exist or create it if not in a xml file using Xpath.
xml file looks like that :

```
<krpano>
    <hotspot name="hs1" ath="0" atv="0"/>
    <hotspot name="hs2" ath="0" atv="0"/>
</krpano>
```

and here is my php code :

```
<?php
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_data = json_decode($str_json);

$file = 'myxmlfile.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$krpano = $xml->xpath("//krpano");
$hotspot = $xml->xpath('//hotspot[@name="'.$json_data->name.'"]');

if ($hotspot){
    $xml->xpath('//hotspot[@name="'.$json_data->name.'"]/@ath->'.$json_data->xpos.'');
    $xml->xpath('//hotspot[@name="'.$json_data->name.'"]/@atv->'.$json_data->ypos.'');
}else{
    $newhs = $krpano[0]->addChild('hotspot');
    $newhs->addAttribute('name', $json_data->name);
    $newhs->addAttribute('ath', $json_data->xpos);
    $newhs->addAttribute('atv', $json_data->ypos);
}

$xml->asXML($file);

?>
```

if the node doesn't exist then it's added, no problem, but if it exist the attribute values aren't changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter attributes like that with XPath,

```
$xml->xpath('//hotspot[@name="'.$json_data->name.'"]/@ath->'.$json_data->xpos.'');
$xml->xpath('//hotspot[@name="'.$json_data->name.'"]/@atv->'.$json_data->ypos.'');
```

you just need to modify them directly from the hotspot you already have...

```
$hotspot[0]['ath'] = $json_data->xpos;
$hotspot[0]['atv'] = $json_data->ypos;
```